# How can I keep elements from overlapping?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, paragraph

I can't seem to get the paragraph and image to not overlap. I'm sure this question has been answered before but I couldn't find a solution. Of course the website is just practice, it's not going to be put anywhere, I just need the practice. I'm using bootstrap 4 by the way.

HTML:

```
<section id="bio">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="display-3 text-center mt-5">Who am I?</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="imgs/person.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 d-block">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
    #bio {
        font-family: 'Poiret One', serif;
    }

    #bio img {
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 350px;
        width: 350px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 5%;
        top: 10%;
        display: block;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 988px) {
        #bio img {
            margin-top: 10%;
        }
    }

    #bio p {
        float: right;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your media query you need to reset your `#bio img` position to static like the example below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 988px) {
    #bio img {
      margin-top: 10%;
      position: static;
    }
}
```

I just hope this help

Answer (score 0):

you can define your width in percentage and try media queries.